# I'd like to find out how to find the current streak of non-negative numbers in a row of data in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example, here is a sample of data:

[image: Sample Data]

I'd like the output for each row to 2,0,1,3,4, respectively.

If this could be done without helpers that would be great. If not, that's okay too.

I've tried to follow something I found that told me to use the INDIRECT function so to be able to reset the range but I'm not sure that exactly fits what I'm trying to do because I just want the current streak, not all streaks in the row.  I've tried to TEXTJOIN and mess with the string along with using COUNTIF from right to left but I couldn't get that to work either.  Thank you!

Comment: Please post your sample data as a markdown table, I recommend https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not been able to give this a try, but in theory this should work:

```
=BYROW(A1:D5,LAMBDA(r,REDUCE(0,r,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y<0,0,x+1)))))
```

Maybe better, avoiding having to use `LAMBDA()` twice;

```
=LEN(TEXTAFTER(1&BYROW(N(A1:D5<0),CONCAT),1,-1))
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it! Most elegant. On the one hand, it's less than two times less efficient than my `XMATCH` (`REDUCE` processes each cell). On the other hand, will OP have as many cells (1M) as it would need to make him care (half a second slower)?

Comment: @VBasic2008, do you have any means of testing this speed? If so, can you test the updated answer too? Curious if it makes a difference (I suspect it should) to leave out one nested LAMBDA helper.

Comment: Sir the updated answer is similar to the one i posted. Only it uses `1` in place of `0` and uses `BYROW()` without `LAMBDA()` construct should be fast enuf!

Comment: First I thought it was a typo. Then I figured out it's an eta. Then I figured out it didn't work because I had an ancient UDF named `CONCAT` in my add-in. For an absurd 1M rows and 10 cols, It's like `REDUCE` takes 9s, `CONCAT` 4s, and the slightly modified `(X)MATCH` 3s on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

### Current Streak of Non-Negatives

- By utilizing the 4th argument `[search_mode]` of `XMATCH` to perform a reverse search, there is no need to flip the matrix vertically.

[image]

```
=LET(matrix,A2:H10,
    n,COLUMNS(matrix),
BYROW(matrix<0,LAMBDA(m,
    IFNA(n-XMATCH(TRUE,m,,-1),n))))
```

Comment: This works if the streak ends at the final column of each row.

Comment: @P.b Not sure what you mean. OP's screenshot and requirement (*"... 2,0,1,3,4..."*) clearly show that he's after the number of consecutive non-negatives after the last negative in each row. Row 2 (`0`, **not** `2`) and row 5 (`4`) remove any doubts.

Comment: I think you may be right, also judging by the word `current` in the title. I created a solution providing the last streak of non-negatives, which may not be what OP is after. Upvoted your solution. And to OP a request to better describe your demands. The title is more descriptive than the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

**Note: My answers below will return the size of the last streak of non-negatives, also if it's not the current.**

I used the following data for this reply:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 0 | 5 | 1 | -2 | -5 | 6 | 4 | -8 |
| **2** | 1 | -5 | -7 | 5 | -8 | -9 | 5 | -4 |
| **3** | -8 | 3 | 7 | 6 | 7 | 6 | 9 | 3 |
| **4** | 8 | 0 | 4 | -1 | -8 | -6 | -1 | -2 |
| **5** | -3 | 0 | -2 | 5 | 8 | 2 | 9 | -4 |
| **6** | -4 | 7 | -8 | 1 | -6 | -9 | 4 | 9 |
| **7** | -2 | -1 | -9 | 0 | -7 | 1 | -5 | 4 |
| **8** | 8 | 3 | -1 | 2 | -9 | 8 | -2 | 6 |
| **9** | 0 | 1 | 2 | -3 | 4 | -8 | 6 | 4 |

If it's strictly integers varying from `-9` to `+9` you could use:

`=MAP(BYROW(A2:H10,CONCAT),LAMBDA(m,LET(t,TEXTSPLIT(m,SEQUENCE(9,,-9,1)),IFERROR(LEN(TAKE(FILTER(t,LEN(t)>1),,-1)),0))))`

Which concatenates the row values of the range by row (`BYROW(A2:H10,CONCAT)`) and `t` splits the concatenated string by any negative integer up to 9, row-wise.
It then filters out the `t` values where the splitted string `t`-length is less than 2 and returns the length of the last remainder of that filter, if any, else it returns 0.

Else (or in both situations) you could use:

```
=BYROW(SCAN(0,A2:H10,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y>-1,IF(COLUMN(y)=1,1,x+1),0))),LAMBDA(z,XLOOKUP(TRUE,z>1,z,0,,-1)))
```

Which creates `z` - a cumulative counter of the number being positive or zero from column A to H - which is used inside `BYROW` to return the last value greater than 1 in each row, or 0 if not found.

This image may help visualize the explanation:
[image]

Comment: While not exactly what I was looking for, this was still useful for something else, so much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `XLOOKUP()` with `SEQUENCE()` function and use the **[search_mode]** from `Search last-to-first`

[image]

---

```
=XLOOKUP(TRUE, A1:D1<0, SEQUENCE(,4,3,-1),4,,-1)
```

---

Or With one single dynamic array to spill use `BYROW()`

```
=BYROW(A1:D5,LAMBDA(x, XLOOKUP(TRUE, x<0, SEQUENCE(,4,3,-1),4,,-1)))
```

---

Another alternative:

[image]

---

```
=BYROW(A1:D5,LAMBDA(α,LEN(TEXTAFTER(0&CONCAT(1-(α<0)),0,-1))))
```

---